# ¿Se puede hacer una división con un acumulador?

Tags: java, bluej, informatica-power-center

La tarea es la siguiente: En el programa anterior del grupo añadir la pregunta “si es hombre o mujer” para que el programa de como salida:

- Promedio de cada alumno
- Si está aprobado o no
- El total de hombres en el grupo
- El total de mujeres en el grupo
- El promedio del grupo y el promedio por género: el promedio en mujeres y el promedio en hombres

Tengo todo, lo único que no me sale es la parte de los promedios de hombres y de mujeres, se suman los promedios pero no se dividen, ¿Qué puedo hacer? Este es el programa que hice:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Promedio_grupal2_0
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    float c1, c2, pg, sp=0, spm=0, pm=0, spf=0, pf=0, ph, pmu;
    int a=0, i=0, cm=0, cf=0;
    String n, op;
    System.out.println("Programa de Promedios");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de alumnos");
    a=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    while (i<a){
      System.out.println("Ingresa los datos que se te piden");
      System.out.println("Nombre:");
      n=teclado.next();
      System.out.println("Género:");
      System.out.println("M. Masculino");
      System.out.println("F. Femenino");
      op=leer.nextLine();
      System.out.println("");
      switch (op)
      {
          case "M":
          System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificación");
          c1=teclado.nextFloat();
          System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificación");
          c2=teclado.nextFloat();
          pm=(c1+c2)/2;
          if (pm>=6){
              System.out.println("Aprobado"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pm);
          }else{
              System.out.println("Reprobado"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pm);
          }
          break;
          case "F":
          System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificación");
          c1=teclado.nextFloat();
          System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificación");
          c2=teclado.nextFloat();
          pf=(c1+c2)/2;
          if (pf>=6){
              System.out.println("Aprobada"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pf);
          }else{
              System.out.println("Reprobada"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pf);
          }
          break;
          default:
      }
      spm=spm+pm;
      spf=spf+pf;
      sp=sp+pm+pf;
      cm=+1;
      cf=+1;
      i++;
    }
    ph=spm/cm;
    pmu=spf/cf;
    pg=(spm+spf)/a;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Mujeres: " + cf);
    System.out.println("Promedio del género femenino es:"+pmu);
    System.out.println("Hombres: " + cm);
    System.out.println("El promedio del género masculino es:"+ph);
    System.out.println("El promedio del grupo es:"+pg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por el orden que estás sumando promedios estás haciendo que al promedio global se le sume tanto el último promedio de hombre como el último promedio de mujer. Claramente estás asumiendo que cuando ingresas un hombre, el valor del promedio de mujer es 0 o que cuando ingresas una mujer, el valor promedio de hombre es 0 pero nunca estás "limpiando" (poniendo en 0) el valor de dichas variables, por lo tanto, en la siguiente repetición se sumaría el valor que tengan esas variables (`pm` y `pf`).

También puedes usar el operador += el cual le suma el valor de la derecha al valor de la variable de la izquierda. Por ejemplo la operación `a += 10;` equivale a poner `a = a + 10;`

Así quedaría tu código corregido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Promedio_grupal2_0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        float c1, c2, pg, sp=0, spm=0, pm=0, spf=0, pf=0, ph, pmu;
        int a=0, i=0, cm=0, cf=0;
        String n, op;
        System.out.println("Programa de Promedios");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de alumnos");
        a=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        while (i<a){
            System.out.println("Ingresa los datos que se te piden");
            System.out.println("Nombre:");
            n=teclado.next();
            System.out.println("Género:");
            System.out.println("M. Masculino");
            System.out.println("F. Femenino");
            op=leer.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            switch (op)
            {
                case "M":
                    System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificación");
                    c1=teclado.nextFloat();
                    System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificación");
                    c2=teclado.nextFloat();
                    pm=(c1+c2)/2;
                    spm += pm;
                    sp += pm;
                    cm += 1;
                    if (pm>=6){
                        System.out.println("Aprobado"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pm);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Reprobado"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pm);
                    }
                    break;
                case "F":
                    System.out.println("Ingresa la primera calificación");
                    c1=teclado.nextFloat();
                    System.out.println("Ingresa la segunda calificación");
                    c2=teclado.nextFloat();
                    pf=(c1+c2)/2;
                    spf += pf;
                    sp += pf;
                    cf += 1;
                    if (pf>=6){
                        System.out.println("Aprobada"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pf);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Reprobada"+" "+n+" "+"tu promedio es:"+pf);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
            i++;
        }
        ph=spm/cm;
        pmu=spf/cf;
        pg=(spm+spf)/a;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Mujeres: " + cf);
        System.out.println("Promedio del género femenino es:"+pmu);
        System.out.println("Hombres: " + cm);
        System.out.println("El promedio del género masculino es:"+ph);
        System.out.println("El promedio del grupo es:"+pg);
    }
}
```